# Define service Time inside a Queue fs2 Streams Scala

Tags: scala, queue, fs2

I'm doing some basic test with queue I want to add a service time before dequeuing the queue.
for instance, the service time is not defined, It will be a mean of 3 seconds it may vary among elements.

Can someone provide some enlightenment?

Here is what I am trying to do: For instance, for 1, it may take 3s, for 2 it may take 5s, for 3 it may take 4s ... 
The idea is the mean service time for example 4 seconds...

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Timer}
import fs2._
import fs2.concurrent.Queue

import scala.concurrent.duration._
class StreamTypeIntToDouble(q: Queue[IO, (Double, String)])(
  implicit timer: Timer[IO]
) {
  def storeInQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {

    Stream(1, 2, 3,4)
      .covary[IO]
      .evalTap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pushing $n to Queue")))
      .map { n =>

        (n.toDouble, "Service")
      }
      .through(q.enqueue)

  }
  def getFromQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    q.dequeue.evalMap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pulling from queue $n")))
  }
}

object Five extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val program = for {
      q <- Queue.bounded[IO, (Double, String)](10)
      b = new StreamTypeIntToDouble(q)
      _ <- b.storeInQueue.compile.drain.start
      _ <- b.getFromQueue.compile.drain
    } yield ()
    program.as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```